How Can Company A Balance DEI Requirements with Language Proficiency Standards?
Company A is a US based company. Recently at company A, the clients are majority of the time always Chinese, Japanese or Indian. They can speak English, and prefer to, but the problem is accents. Company A's many current employees have problems communicating with these accents.
Therefore, company A wants to add this in their job requirements:

Candidate must be good at understanding Chinese, Japanese and Indian accents of English. Candidate must be good at speaking English intellegible to people accustomed to Chinese, Japanese and/or Indian accents.

The problem is that this requirement naturally favors candidates with ethnicity from one of these regions. How can Company A balance DEI requirements with Language(accent) proficiency standards?

Edit: DEI stands for diversity, equity and inclusion.

"The problem is that this requirement naturally favors candidates with ethnicity from one of these regions" - Not necessarily

Sometimes genuine business requirements do favour certain groups. You simply can't employ (say) someone who speaks only French if your clients want to speak German.

"Candidate must be good at speaking English intellegible to people accustomed to Chinese, Japanese and/or Indian accents." - This requirements sounds a bit silly, sounds like you are requiring candidates to be able to "speak English with indian/chinese accent"... neutral-accent English (whatever that is, hehe, but we mean more US/UK english I bet, and still there are accents on different parts of US/UK but not the point...) should be perfectly understood by people used to other accents

@TheDemonLord DEI is a widely accepted and supported initiative, with real world examples of it both failing and succeeding. When correctly implemented it has nothing to do with passing over a more qualified candidate for one who is less so. Calling it a "toxic idea" and "cancer" is not productive for anyone, especially not for the OP who clearly states they have requirements to hit as a company.

I am white American.  I once worked for a guy who was Chinese from Cambodia, and he couldn't understand the Vietnamese people at the business next door.  So he'd tell me in English, and I'd translate it to them in English, and then translate back to him in English.  So maybe it favors people from that region, but it certainly doesn't exclude ethnicities.

It is always a bad idea to sacrifice customers needs as a company policy.

DEI is meant to promote fairness of opportunity for minority groups. Therefore it might come into play if you have multiple candidates who are equally skilled (or unskilled) at understanding these accents, but it would not mean accepting a candidate from country X who can't understand a certain accent over a candidate from country Y who can understand that accent - and thus perform the job better - just because you've already hired multiple people from country Y. To ignore the target language proficiency standards in the pursuit of DEI would be incorrect. DEI comes secondary to determining the skills and characteristics you are looking for in a candidate.  I also want to add that it might make more sense to look for candidates who are conversational or proficient in one or more of these languages as opposed to understanding or speaking the accent. This is an actual resume item that you can measure and use to objectively rank candidates. Being able to understand a regional accent is IMO pretty subjective and probably hard to verify.

It's not even being able to understand an accent, but being understood by someone used to an accent, which seems even more subjective and ill-defined

@mattfreake That also means being able to navigate cultural expectations.  Some cultures may be more inclined to answer how they feel, rather than what is being asked.

I would rephrase your requirement to something like:
"Candidate needs to be able to communicate with people with limited English proficiency or strong accents."
without specifying any particular kind of accent. You can then test this skill in interviews with the particular strong accents that are common in your company. This tells candidates for your company that such skills will be needed but in practice will hardly prevent people from applying because they feel they don't have that skill.
